# Dir cmd prompt omits files - why?

Tags: excel, cmd, dir

I am using the following cmd prompt to acquire a list of the files and folders in a directory:  v:>dir/s>name.txt.

The text file seems to be too small for my directory (3700 items), as it omits items listed lower on the directory.  I initially thought it was the size of the text file causing the problem because of the last comment in this thread:

[Is there a size limit on a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393833/is-there-a-size-limit-on-a-text-file)

I tried changing the prompt to v:\dir/s>name.xls.  This worked, but when I opened the excel sheet, the list still omitted files lower down in the directory.  This is surprising because according to microsoft,

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

an Excel sheet can be filled up to 65, 536 rows, and my newly sheet created only went to row 3561.

I could solve the problem by running the cmd prompt at the subfolder level, but I will have to run this command many, many times.  If you have a solution, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Changing the extension of a file does not magically change its format. `dir /s` produces text output. Changing it to `dir /s > name.jpg` would not produce an image of the directory content, and changing it to `name.xls` does not produce an Excel spreadsheet - it's a text file that happens to have an extension that is registered with Excel as the handler, but it's still a text file.

Comment: How many rows do you get in the .txt file?  What OS are you using?  As a FYI text files do not have limits.  Whatever is going on is related to the DIR command functionality.

Comment: To Ken White: Thank you for your information regarding the file extensions.  To Alan Waage: I'm using Microsoft Windows.  I ran the DIR command again and found that the number of lines in the text file was 36 709.  This was a larger number than the Excel file I produced a couple days ago, so I checked to see if various files had been captured on the list, and they all were.  I am quite happy to have a complete list.  If I figure out what I was doing wrong previously I will let you know.

Comment: Oh man, I still need help.  I ran the exact same command prompt five times.  And each time it created a text file with a different number of lines! (More specifically: 2891, 2110, 3901, 8873, 2189) What is going on here?  I am deriving the directory from a Network drive so I thought other people may be adding/deleting files.  So I did the same test on my personal drive, and I similarly got a variation.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the files, hidden or system or not.

```
dir /b /s /a-d >file.txt
```